# Enumerate files with case sensitivity in VBScript?

Tags: vbscript, wmi, case-sensitive

I am using the following VBScript code snippet to enumerate all files in my c:\Scripts\ folder:

```
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
   & "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colFiles = objWMIService. _
   ExecQuery("Select * from CIM_DataFile where Path = '\\Scripts\\'")

For Each objFile in colFiles
    Wscript.Echo objFile.Name 
Next
```

Unfortunately objFile.Name returns the path in all lower-case. It is important to me to retrieve the case of all file names, i.e. NewFileOne.txt, should not be returned as newfileone.txt.

Is there a way to enumerate files with case-sensitivity in VBScript?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the FileSystemObject, you will get back names with the case preserved

[Files Collection (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz72a8c0(VS.85).aspx#Mtps_DropDownFilterText)

```
dim objFSO, path, fldr, f, msg
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set fldr = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Scripts")

For Each f in fldr.Files
    MsgBox f.name
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the `CIM_DataFile.Name` property, the `FileName` and `Extension` properties are case sensitive. So, if it's necessary for you to use WMI, you can retrieve the file name and extension separately:

```
WScript.Echo objFile.FileName & "." & objFile.Extension
```

Answer (score 0):

Mike's solution is better, but here's A VERY UGLY alternative:

Using the shell exec execute the following command:

```
dir c:\scripts /B>file.txt
```

Now "file.txt" contains the file listed with proper casing.

Sorry, it's ugly but works.